# How to use selected value in dropdown in php?

Tags: php

I am using following code for dropdown in php

```
$iname=$row['name'];

// Write query for Items dropdown.
$iquery = "SELECT * FROM items";

// Execute it, or return the error message if there's a problem.
$iresult = mysqli_query($con, $iquery) or die(mysql_error());
$edropdown = "<select name='epin' style=\"height:37px; width:222px;\">";
while($erow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($iresult))
{
    $edropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$erow['name']}'>{$erow['name']}</option>";
}
$edropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
echo $edropdown;
```

I am using this code in an edit form. I want to use selected value ($iname) in the dropdown. How can set selected value in this code. Regards

Comment: Compare values and output `selected` for `option`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare this value $iname with your options, use below code:

```
$edropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$erow['name']}' ({$erow['name']}==$iname)?'selected':''>{$erow['name']}</option>";
```